# Switching from SQL to Redis as standalone

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session, caching, redis

**Background info before question**

I use state session a lot to store my complex objects, I am also using at max like 8 tables. On those 8 tables I am using like about 25 SP to join users based on user id and some key values that the user selects. All this is done on SQL Server database.

1. zip codes spatial values
2. male or female
3. has pictures
4. approved profile
5. registered account(paying for services)

I store Images in a file system on my application server. I store the path on my db table.

**Use Case**

Dating website, unique payloads most of the time such as searching based on a certain criteria, updating and fetching personal profile with photos. I am using asp.net MVC, and this is a website only. (separate web pages for responsive designs for other devices)

**Question**

Can I just use Redis as my primary data store, instead of using SQL server Database based on my use case?

**Key Points**

I don't on plan on having more than like 10-12 total tables in the future. The data input are mostly strings. When I want to persist a complex object like profile information and image paths I use a Session State. I love what I read about the speed of Redis, and I see it being counter productive to duplicating updates to both Redis and a DB if I stack them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can easily replace your database with Redis because you are missing things like FK, indexes, constraints (Redis is a NoSQL so you don't have any relational attributes). So you will end up building those yourself, especially the indexes for your 25 stored procs which can become pretty complex stuff. Also the fact that you have 25 stored procs for your 8 tables kind of tells me you have quite some logic here which will be even harder to move to Redis or your application layer.
Sure, adding Redis to your stack is not easy and it will make your application more complex, so you must weight the benefits and the drawbacks. And Redis because it keeps all the stuff in memory it is best suited for a cache layer.

Comment: Thanks for your input, the reason I am responding so fast is because I am actually on SO trying to stack Redis with my DB. Working on it with Service Stack Redis. Let's see how it goes.

Comment: Yea I know I want it as my cache layer, a lot of research has led me there. Instead of storing objects in my session I am looking at the different ways I could store it in Redis as a cache using some of the api's provided by Service Stack. Still confused as hell but, I am smarter than I was when I asked this question lol

Comment: What is exactly you are trying to optimize here, what is your main problem? Storing objects in Session is faster than storing and retrieving from Redis, assuming your Session is in proc. Unless you have poblems with your web server memory or thinking of something like autoscale.

Comment: I plan on implementing signalr websockets/long polling in the future. If I have to scale in the future, in proc sessions will move to session states, which I don't want. Definitely not with the Database. I don't want to share session id's in a cookie openly. It just feels like bad practice. I also don't want to serialize and deserialize complex objects in a session. I would rather have them cached in redis. So as of now I have no problems, but I sense down the road my current approach will not scale well at all. Service stack provides alot out of the box, and that's something I like.